# configure localhost https glassfish

Tags: java, https, glassfish

I am using Glassfish 3.1, I am trying to run a JSF application under https localhost.

Is it possible?

I tried to configure glassfish listeners, where I have a listener on port 80. I see glassfish has another listener but it is not running, why? Can I run an application like this: https://localhost or configure another host on windows to test my application that only runs on https?

thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure you ask your question **in the text** and very clearly. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my junk english...

I found a solution: I had to configure the listener 2 to listen to the port 443, so I could access my: https://localhost. 443 is the default port to HTTPS, as well as port 80 is the default to HTTP.